# LWC data table select/deselect the rows dynamically

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

Spent hours together to figure out how to do this? before I came here. I am trying to do the client-side pagination using the data table. The pagination works fine, however, I am not able to achieve the row deselection along with all the pages.

Selecting rows working fine, I keep adding the selected rows to the array and carry forward to all the pages when we go back and forth rows get selected according to the array of ids. however, when I unselect the rows, it will not remove from the master array because I am not able to get the id, what is unselected.

Is there any way, we can achieve, otherwise I have to go with a custom HTML table.

**html**:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="List of Records" icon-name="custom:custom9">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">   
            <div >
                <lightning-datatable 
                    key-field="id"
                    data={data}
                    columns={columns}                                      
                    onrowselection={getSelectedRecords}                    
                    onrowaction={handleRowActions}>
                </lightning-datatable>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <p class="slds-m-vertical_medium content">
                     Displaying {startingRecord} to {endingRecord} of {totalRecountCount} records.
                     Page {page} of {totalPage}. </p>
            <c-paginator onprevious={previousHandler} onnext={nextHandler}></c-paginator>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**JS**:

```
/* eslint-disable vars-on-top */
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import { LightningElement,track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { fireEvent } from 'c/pubsub';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';


export default class TableUtilityComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track page = 1; //this is initialize for 1st page
    @track items = []; //it contains all the records.
    @track data = []; //data to be display in the table
    @track columns; //holds column info.
    @track startingRecord = 1; //start record position per page
    @track endingRecord = 0; //end record position per page
    @track pageSize = 20; //default value we are assigning
    @track totalRecountCount = 0; //total record count received from all retrieved records
    @track totalPage = 0; //total number of page is needed to display all records
    _selectedRecords=[];

    // private
    @track _pagerData=[];
    _thispageselectedrows=[];
    _finalselectedRows=[];
    // private
    @track _pageColumnData=[];

    @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;

    @api
    get pagerData() {
        return this._pagerData;
    }

    @api
    get columnsData() {
        return this._pageColumnData;
    }

    set columnsData(value) { 
        this.setAttribute('columnsData', value);       
        this._pageColumnData = value;
        this.setup();
    }

    set pagerData(value) {
        this.setAttribute('pagerData', value);
        this._pagerData = value;
        this.setup();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.setup();
    }

    handleRowActions(event) {
        let actionName = event.detail.action.name;
        let row = event.detail.row;
        // eslint-disable-next-line default-case
        switch (actionName) {
            case 'record_details':
                this.viewCurrentRecord(row);
                break;
            case 'edit':
                this.editCurrentRecord(row);
                break;
            case 'delete':
                this.deleteCons(row);
                break;
        }
    }


    // view the current record details
    viewCurrentRecord(currentRow) {       
        fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'clickedRecord', currentRow);
    }

    getSelectedRecords(event) {
        const selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows;      

       for ( let i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++ ){             
            if ( !this._selectedRecords.includes(selectedRows[i].id) )
                this._selectedRecords =[...this._selectedRecords, selectedRows[i].id];
       }

       console.log('Total Selected Records: '+JSON.stringify(this._selectedRecords));




        /*fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'selectedRecords', this.selectedRecords);*/    
    }

    setup() {
        console.log('hello');
        this.columns = this._pageColumnData;
        this.items = this._pagerData;       
        this.totalRecountCount = this._pagerData.length; //here it is 23
        this.totalPage = Math.ceil(this.totalRecountCount / this.pageSize); //here it is 5
        this.data = this.items.slice(0,this.pageSize); 
        this.endingRecord = this.pageSize;
        //this.columns = columns;
        this.error = undefined;
    }

    //clicking on previous button this method will be called
    previousHandler() {

        if (this.page > 1) {
            this.page = this.page - 1; //decrease page by 1
            this.displayRecordPerPage(this.page);
        }
    }

    //clicking on next button this method will be called
    nextHandler() {

        if((this.page<this.totalPage) && this.page !== this.totalPage){
            this.page = this.page + 1; //increase page by 1
            this.displayRecordPerPage(this.page);            
        }             
    }

    //this method displays records page by page
    displayRecordPerPage(page){

        var el = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable');   
        el.selectedRows = this._selectedRecords;

        this.startingRecord = ((page -1) * this.pageSize);
        this.endingRecord = (this.pageSize * page);

        this.endingRecord = (this.endingRecord > this.totalRecountCount) 
                            ? this.totalRecountCount : this.endingRecord; 

        this.data = this.items.slice(this.startingRecord, this.endingRecord);
        this.startingRecord = this.startingRecord + 1;
    }  
}
```

[image]

[image]